# Can not run the visual studio project system.web.mvc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I get this error:

[image]

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is one file missing: "nuget.targets".

Do you have any extra information about it?, have you tried to run it in a different Visual Studio installation?, different computer, maybe?.

If I were you I would clean everything and try to run the project again.

I guess that you used this: http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started as your guide to install nuget. I would recommend to install it again and if you don't success with it come back and give us extra information.